# Eror E11000 duplicate key error (Mongodb via Linux VM)?

Tags: mongodb

So when I execute mongoimport  --port 35524 --db city --collection inspections ./city_inspections.json I keep getting the error E11000 duplicate key error
over and over

According to the guide for class its what I listed above minus the addition of --port 35524 but it doesn't do anything unless I include the port

[image: Image of the error]

```
I'm running mongo via Linux VM
```

Comment: this error just says that you insert duplicated records in city.inspection._id field

Comment: Yeah but nothing is duplicated. I was pulling db and collection with .json
So I'm trying to figure out how to negate that error
I've tried different variants of typing but same error

Comment: the error above straightforwardly says that duplicated key is city.inspection._id

Comment: The data that you are importing has already been imported. The key **_id** is a unique identifier for each document. To reimport the same data again, review the command line option **--drop**. Since that will delete data, make sure you understand what that option does.